# Change the value of a cell based on another cell value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this problem, I want to change the value of column Q based on what word is in Column U. But here comes the tricky part, in column U I could have different words which actually will mean the same, here is the index: (left side are the words of column U and right side their meaning)

```
REOK: CONCLUSIVE RESOLVED  
INIC: IN PROCESS  
PLAN: IN PROCESS  
VERI: IN PROCESS  
OPER: IN PROCESS  
FISC: IN PROCESS   
OTRA: IN PROCESS  
TERC: IN PROCESS   
SERV: IN PROCESS  
PROG: IN PROCESS  
FREN: CONCLUSIVE DENIED  
INFO: CONCLUSIVE DENIED  
INEX: CONCLUSIVE DENIED  
IM01: CONCLUSIVE DENIED  
IM02: CONCLUSIVE DENIED  
IM03: CONCLUSIVE DENIED  
IM04: CONCLUSIVE DENIED  
IM05: CONCLUSIVE DENIED  
CANC: CONCLUSIVE DENIED
```

So, for example if in (column U - Row 1) I have "REOK", I would like column Q to automatically change to "CONCLUSIVE RESOLVED".

That would be the first part, but I have another issue. Column U is imported from another app every 3 days, so I could actually have more recent information than the report has so in some cases I would need to manually change column Q to the states of right side of index (probably until I receive the next report in 3 days) without changing the formula of the cell in case the report which comes in 3 days updates the state of the case.

I have tried an attempt of inserting an array formula but I encountered the problem of not being able to manually change column Q because that would delete the array formula itself.

Comment: Hello! Column U is the one updated each 3 days? (You said Q)

Comment: Hi Martin, ty for the reply. Indeed i was wrong i meant Column U. Your idea could be one of the possibilities, but not all the cells inside Column Q have a value on Column U (only 5k cells of 13k total have this states in column U) so the other 8k cells should actually be modifiable by hand everyday. And its important that the one of the 3 states is written in the Column Q for each cell because Q is exported to different sheets which needs the cell to be filled. @Martín

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new column:

[image: ![]

With this formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(V2:V<>"",V2:V,IF(U2:U="","",ifs(REGEXMATCH(U2:U,"(?i)REOK"),"CONCLUSIVE RESOLVED",REGEXMATCH(U2:U,"(?i)INIC|PLAN|VERI|OPER|FISC|ORA|TERC|SERV|PROGR"),"IN PROCESS",REGEXMATCH(U2:U,"(?i)FREN|INFO|INEX|IM01|IM02|IM03|IM04|IM05|CANC"),"CONCLUSIVE DENIED"))))
```

When a handwritten value is written in V column Q will show that value or else it will show U value. It's an option to do this rightaway, obviously (PS: no, you can't have an arrayformula and overwrite a value).

Option B, a second workaround-step is to add a script that every time you manually insert a value in Q it will be moved to column V:

```
const destinCol = 22

function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.range.getColumn() == 17) {
    moveValue()
  }
}

function moveValue(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet()
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange()
  var row = range.getRow()
  range.moveTo(sheet.getRange(row,destinCol))
  //range.clearContent()

}

function onOpen(){
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .createMenu("Clear")
  .addItem("Clear Col "+destinCol,"clearCol")
  .addToUi()

}

function clearCol() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet()
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()
  sheet.getRange(1,destinCol,lastRow,1).clearContent()

}
```

Change that first line with the number of column if you don't want it to be V. I also added there a function that will create a menu to clear entire V column when the data is updated.
Try it [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zCMq1IzZzL2SdTIzfx0YTnaLohBY549TbO4FeHA2Sh4/edit?usp=sharing)

---

Comment: Such a great help! i´ll try to implement the code to appscript today and see if it does not cause any issue with the other code inside it. If everything worked fine, i´ll let you know. Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: If you have any code working for the update, you can trigger also that clearCol function too. You may want to set .getActiveSheet() to .getSheetbyName() and put the name of your sheet between brackets ;)

Answer (score -1):

In Google Sheets, you have to add a column (it can be hidden) that does the following:

```
"=QUERY(sap!A:B;"SELECT B WHERE A = '"&A2&"')"
```

taking into account that "sap" is a tab in the same work, A is the IDs column, B the status and &A2& is the cell that has the SUASI/SAP ID.
Then you have to add the result column where you put an IFS concatenating all the sequences and results something like this:

```
=IFS(B2 = "START"; "IN PROCESS";B2 = "PLAN"; "IN PROCESS";B2 = "VERI"; "IN PROCESS";B2 = "OPER"; "IN PROCESS";B2 = " REOK"; "CONCLUSIVE RESOLVED";B2 = "FISC"; "IN PROCESS";B2 = "INEX"; "CONCLUSIVE DENIED";B2 = "OTHER"; "IN PROCESS";B2 = "INFO"; "CONCLUSIVE DENIED ";B2 = "TERC"; "IN PROCESS";B2 = "SERV"; "IN PROCESS";B2 = "FREN"; "CONCLUSIVE DENIED";B2 = "PROG"; "IN PROCESS";B2 = "IM01 "; "CONCLUSIVE DENIED";B2 = "IM02"; "CONCLUSIVE DENIED";B2 = "IM03"; "CONCLUSIVE DENIED";B2 = "IM04"; "CONCLUSIVE DENIED";B2 = "IM05"; "CONCLUSIVE DENIED" ;B2 = "CANCEL"; "CONCLUSIVE DENIED")
)
```

Being B2 the hidden column that we did previously.

Comment: This question is about Google Sheets, not Excel.

Comment: @Rubén Really bro? Is the same. If you try to do it in google sheets it will work

Comment: Have you already tested the above in Google Sheets? Formulas should not be enclosed inside quotes by the other hand it's not clear how this address answers the OP concern regarding manually editing column Q. P.S. if you will edit the question again replace "work" by "spreadsheet".